# Update package.json version with release-please-action in monorepo

Tags: github-actions, package.json

I have a monorepo with a `web` folder and an `api` folder. The former contains a react application and a `package.json`, while the latter contains a python api. I use the release-please-action for github to create changelog and increment versions:

```
jobs:
  release-please:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: google-github-actions/release-please-action@v3
        id: release
        with:
          release-type: simple
          extra-files: |
            api/pyproject.toml
            api/src/app.py
            web/package.json
```

For `pyproject.toml` and `app.py`, I can add the `# x-release-please-version` comment to let release-please know which line to find and increment the version. But for the json file that obviously is not an alternative.

I found a [guide](https://github.com/googleapis/release-please/blob/main/docs/customizing.md#updating-arbitrary-json-files) explaining how to update json files, but when I tried to update the action step to use an array

```
          extra-files: >
            [
                api/pyproject.toml,
                api/src/app.py,
                {
                  "type": "json",
                  "path": "web/package.json",
                  "jsonpath": "$.version"
                }
            ]
```

, I got `file [ did not exist`.

I also tried configuring the workflow with release-please-config, but that failed as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I just had to solve the same issue, and I managed like this:

In your GitHub action workflow file, change the `release-type` value from `simple` to `node`, like so:

```json
jobs:
  release-please:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: google-github-actions/release-please-action@v3
        id: release
        with:
          release-type: node
          extra-files: |
            api/pyproject.toml
            api/src/app.py
            web/package.json
```

And now the pull request from Release Please will also update the `version` value of your `package.json`.

As per the documentation, the [Release Types Supported](https://github.com/google-github-actions/release-please-action?tab=readme-ov-file#release-types-supported) has the value `node`, which means, and I quote: "A Node.js repository, with a package.json and CHANGELOG.md".

I hope that helps

Comment: Works great and should be accepted.